# Delete A Specific File From Directories Based On FIND Results

Tags: shell, find, command, delete-file

I have the following find command that searches all subdirectories and lists those folders that contain a *.RAR **AND** a *.MKV file.

```
find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print | sort
```

What I want to do now is to delete the *.MKV file from those directories.

For example, the above command finds FILEA.RAR and FILEB.MKV and lists the directory as DIRECTORY_CHARLIE. I would like to be able to have the above code, also delete the FILEB.MKV file, well delete the found MKV file from each directory that had both file types.

To start, I've created "_TestDir" with the following subfolders:

```
@useroneserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Feb 27 19:31 Folder01
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Feb 27 19:32 Folder02
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Feb 27 19:32 Folder03
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Feb 27 19:33 Folder04
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Feb 27 19:34 Folder05
```

Each folder has 2 files, except Folder03, which only has one file.

```
userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder01 -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Mar  1 20:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 userone userone 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:31 File1.rar
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:30 FileA.mkv

userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder02 -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Mar  1 20:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 userone userone 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:32 File2.rar
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:31 FileB.mkv

userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder03 -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  30 Mar  1 20:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 userone userone 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:32 FileC.mkv

userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder04 -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Mar  1 20:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 userone userone 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:33 File4.rar
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:33 FileD.mkv

userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder05 -all
drwxr-xr-x 2 userone userone  50 Mar  1 20:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 userone userone 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:34 File5.rar
-rw-r--r-- 1 userone userone   0 Feb 27 19:33 FileE.mkv
```

When I run the command in the original post, I get this:

```
userone@remoteserver ~/files/_TestDir $ find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print | sort
./Folder01
./Folder02
./Folder04
./Folder05
```

That is what I expect to see as the results, since folders 1, 2, 4 & 5 have a file of each of the extensions that I am looking for (*.rar & *.mkv), where as folder 3 only has one *.mkv file.

I have not tried to add any delete function since I have no clue where to start.

What I would like to happen is to be able to remove/delete the following
files:

```
FileA.mkv from Folder01
FileB.mkv from Folder02
FileD.mkv from Folder04
FileE.mkv from Folder05
```

Nothing gets deleted from Folder03 since it does not have a .RAR AND a .MKV file, it only has the .MKV. Hope this helps clarify.

Thank you for your assistance.

Regards.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can try out some things.  Add a test directory and file structure and the output of the command you put in your question, from that test structure.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. New here and thought I posted enough but here it goes.

Comment: So I created a "_TestDir" with the following folders and files under it:
<br/>
user@server ~/files/_TestDir $ ls -all
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 fatbob fatbob 105 Feb 27 19:30 .
drwxrwx--- 7 fatbob fatbob 105 Feb 27 19:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:31 Folder01
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:32 Folder02
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:32 Folder03
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:33 Folder04
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:34 Folder05

Comment: Each folder has 2 files, except Folder03, which only has FIleE.mkv

user@server ~/files/_TestDir $ ls Folder01 -all
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 fatbob fatbob  50 Feb 27 19:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 fatbob fatbob 105 Feb 27 19:30 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatbob fatbob   0 Feb 27 19:30 FileA.mkv
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatbob fatbob   0 Feb 27 19:31 FileB.rar

Folder02: FileC.mkv / FileD.rar
Folder03: FileE.mkv
Folder04: FileG.mkv / FileH.rar
Folder05: FileI.mkv / FileJ.rar

Comment: When I run the command in the original post, I get this:

user@server ~/files/_TestDir $ find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print | sort
./Folder01
./Folder02
./Folder04
./Folder05

Comment: I have not tried to add any delete function since I have no clue where to start. What I would like to happen is to be able to remove/delete the following files:

FileA.mkv from Folder01  
FileC.mkv from Folder02  
FileG.mkv from Folder04  
FileI.mkv from Folder05  

Nothing gets deleted from Folder03 since it does not have a .RAR AND a .MKV file, it only has the .MKV.

Hope this helps clarifiy.

Comment: Please add the details in the question.  You can edit existing questions. Figuring out what you wrote in comments, without formatting, is very difficult.

Comment: I've updated the original post @Nic3500. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `xargs` to run `rm` which will delete the files.
And define the replacement string, using the `-I` option of `xargs`.

Using your directory structure, you can do:

```
find -type d -exec sh -c '[ -f "$0"/*.rar ] && [ -f "$0"/*.mkv ]' '{}' \; -print | sort | xargs -I % sh -c "rm -f %/File?.mkv"
```

I took your exact `find` command, and added this:

```
| xargs -I % sh -c "rm -f %/File?.mkv"
```

Explanation

- when `find` runs, it will output

  ```
  ./Folder01
  ./Folder02
  ./Folder04
  ./Folder05
  ```
- Since `xargs` is used with the `-I %` option, it will run the command, replacing `%` with each directory (like in a loop, one by one).  You could use another character than `%`, but avoid wildcard characters.
- The command that `xargs` will run is `sh -c "rm -f %/File?.mkv"`
- It will therefore do the following commands, in succession:

  ```
  sh -c "rm -f Folder01/File?.mkv"
  sh -c "rm -f Folder02/File?.mkv"
  sh -c "rm -f Folder04/File?.mkv"
  sh -c "rm -f Folder05/File?.mkv"
  ```

Obviously, you can adjust as required.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly in the _TestDir but did not in the actual directory I need to run this in and I know why. The filenames in "production" aren't actually called File?.mkv so I needed to make the filename dynamic too but I realized that the filename will always be the same as the folder name. So I just replaced the "File?" with the % and it all worked like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: Actually, it seems as though in some instances the case changes between the filename and the directory name. So if the directory is "FolderName" and the filename is "foldername.mkv", this does not work. Any way to account for this in some fashion?

Comment: This can be scripted, but I would not try to do it via a one-liner.  It would be a crazy line, it is easier to debug and write a script for complex operations.  In variableA, store the directory name, in variableB store the file name, lowercase both, if they match, delete the file.  For the lowercase operation, you can use `lowerA=$(echo $variableA | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')`

Comment: Thank you.

Unfortunately, 1) I am not much of a coder and would have no clue on how to script this and 2) even if I were to figure it out, this is a SEEDBOX and not sure if scripts have to have elevated permissions to be able to run those.